# firestoreConnect Query - you can only perform equality comparisons on null ( via whereEqualTo )

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore, react-redux-firebase

I am stuck with this issue from last 2 days and now i decided to post it in here. i don't know what is going wrong and where. everything seems fine and working in screen where i used the where query but when i moved to another screen and try to signout from the app this error pops out.

[image: react native firebaseconnect error]

And here is my firestore collection structure :

[image: react native firebaseconnect error]

Now here is my code which i wrote to acheive this :

```
    //console.log(state.firestore.data['otherSquads'])
    return {
        auth: state.firebase.auth,
        totalSquads: state.firestore.ordered.squad,
        currUser: state.firestore.data['currentUser']
    }
}

export default compose(
    connect(mapStateToProps),
    firestoreConnect(props => {
        const userid = props.auth.uid;
        return [
            {
                collection: 'squad', 
                where: [['squadMembers', 'array-contains', userid]],
                orderBy: ['createdAt', 'desc']
            },
            {
                collection: 'users',
                doc: userid,
                storeAs: 'currentUser'
            }
        ]
    })
)(SquadScreen);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the user signs out, your `userid` parameter in this code becomes `null`:

```
where: [['squadMembers', 'array-contains', userid]],
```

As the error message says, you cannot pass `null` to `whereEqualTo` operations. It is only valid in `array-contains` operations.

The solution is to detach the query listener before you sign the user out. I've never done this with `redux-firebase` myself, but this [`detachListener` method](https://github.com/prescottprue/redux-firestore/blob/06e4bb47acac5246aac8145a4dd9d2cdd70454ad/src/utils/query.js#L361) seems promising.